# Type hint of generic function?

Tags: python, function, generics, type-hinting, pylance

Consider the following code:

```
from typing import List, TypeVar, Callable

_T = TypeVar('_T')

# A generic function that takes a string and a list of stuff and that returns one of the stuff
Prompter = Callable[[str, List[_T]], _T]

# A function that takes such a Prompter and do things with it
ActionDef = Callable[[Prompter[_T]], None]

# A register of all ActionDef's
ACTION_DEFS: List[ActionDef[_T]] = []
```

I get an error from pylance on `List[ActionDef[_T]]`:

```
Type variable "_T" has no meaning in this context
```

If I do `List[ActionDef]` instead, it also complains:

```
Expected type arguments for generic type alias "ActionDef"
```

Basically it wants me to do something like `ACTION_DEFS: List[ActionDef[int]] = []` which defeats the whole point.

Question1: how to define write `ACTION_DEFS` typing declaration?

Question2 (where the title comes from): Is there a way to define `Prompter` in such way that I don't need to carry the `[_T]` along everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The first error you encountered is because using a type variable with a generic type creates a generic alias, not a concrete type. You must annotate variables with concrete types, hence the error.

The second error, I assume it's specific to `pylance`, because in `mypy` an unparameterized generic type is equivalent to substituting all type variables for `Any`. So the type `List[ActionDef]` is equivalent to `List[ActionDef[Any]]`.

---

From what I understand, you actually want your `ActionDef` alias to match any function that takes a `Prompter` **of any type**, i.e. `Prompter[Any]`. In this case, you can define it as:

```
ActionDef = Callable[[Prompter[Any]], None]
# or, if you're using mypy:
# ActionDef = Callable[[Prompter], None]

# Now `ActionDef` is no longer generic.
ACTION_DEFS: List[ActionDef] = []
```